# How to add file to project but not TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix

I'm in the process of adding a WIX project to my solution and I'm using HEAT to create the files list.  I've been having trouble getting builds to work unless the files list(wxs) is checked out.

[I came across this tutorial](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/02/23/WiX-3-Tutorial-Generating-filedirectory-fragments-with-Heat.exe.aspx) and it says:

> "If you have source control you have to include the FilesFragment.wxs
>   into your project but remove its source control binding. "

Is this possible in TFS 2010 with VS2010?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click/Select on the file.

In VS, go File Menu / Source Control / Exclude file from source control.

This method only allows you to do this one file at a time.

The file will still be in your project and will not be under source control.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like dynamically emitting installation authoring at build time for abouta dozen reasons but if you really are going to do it, perhaps you should consider checking it out and checking it in so that you have some histroy of what actually happened from build to build.

Otherwise if your installation behavior changes from one build to another build in an unexpected and undesirable way, you really aren't going to have any tracability other then diffing MSI's as to what went wrong.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the mainstream approach the more I read.  Thanks for reinforcing it with me :)